# Cant count all the objects of a json array which is stored in mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have stored in my mongodb a document which includes a Json array of objects. It looks like:

```
{"_id":ObjectId("5ec3a08140a8e1365cbf7e6f")
   "boats":[   //json array of boat objects 
      {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ec3a08140a8e1365cbf7e73"), 
        "model": "benet", 
        "year" : "01/01/2019", 
        price : 200 
      },
      {...}, 
      {...}, 
      {...} // other objects
   ]
}
```

I am new to mongodb and I am trying to count the objects in the array boats, where the price is for example 200. I have tried as following:

```
db.getCollection('boatsCompany').find({'price' : 200}).count()
```

The problem is that it counts and returns only 1 and there could be more objects with `'price': 200` in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to search no of boats with price 200 in all the documents then use the below query,

```
db.getCollection('boatsCompany').aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         prices: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$boats",
               as: "boat",
               cond: { $eq: [ "$$boat.price", 200 ] }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $project: {
         numberOfBoats: { $size: "$prices" }
      }
   }
])
```

and if you want for a single company than you should put $match first with the company id then search for the boats

```
db.getCollection('boatsCompany').aggregate([
   { $match : { "_id" : ObjectId("5ec3a08140a8e1365cbf7e6f") } },
   {
      $project: {
         prices: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$boats",
               as: "boat",
               cond: { $eq: [ "$$boat.price", 200 ] }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $project: {
         numberOfBoats: { $size: "$prices" }
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: if the price was in an embedded array how could i use the condition in aggregate? I tried to make the input as you show me previously and in the condition like cond:{$eq:["$boat.array.price"]}... But didnt work. How can i navigate it to point into an array?